# Transaction isn't being completed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

I want the payment transaction to complete once the download transaction has completed but when the download finishes for some reason the transaction state is not completed. Do i have to put the payment transaction back in the queue after the download is complete here is more code.

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];


}
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {

        if(transaction.downloads){
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
        }else{

        switch (transaction.transactionState){

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
  }
}
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads;
{
    for (SKDownload *download in downloads) {

        if (download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateFinished) {
            [self processDownload:download]; //handle download 
            // now we're done
            NSLog(@"Download finished");
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:download.transaction];

//Do I need to add the payment transaction back in the queue? Im worried the payment will go through twice?

        } else if (download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateActive) {

            NSString *productID = download.contentIdentifier; // in app purchase identifier
            NSTimeInterval remaining = download.timeRemaining; // secs
            float progress = download.progress; // 0.0 -> 1.0
            NSLog(@"Product ID:%@", productID);
            NSLog(@"Time remaining: %f", remaining);
            NSLog(@"Download progress percent: %f", progress);

        } else {    // waiting, paused, failed, cancelled
            NSLog(@"Warn: not handled: %d", download.downloadState);
        }
    }
}
```

These are my methods I created for my transaction state if it matters at all? None of them are being executed anyways so I don't think it matter but here it is.

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    if(transaction.downloads){
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
        NSLog(@"Download exists");
    }else{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on an un-jailbroken `ios` device, not the simulator?

Comment: yes, the transaction worked BEFORE I added the code to start the download.

Comment: yes as in I'm testing on a unjailbroken iOS device